# Is there a xsl:for-each-group equivalent in XQuery?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

As the title says, is there a xsl:for-each-group equivalent in XQuery?

What I'm trying to do is get a subtree of elements, change the data structure and iterate through an xml like that.

For example

clients.xml

```
<clients>
  <client>
  <fname>Sam</fname>
  <order>6789</order>
  </client>
</client>
```

products.xml

```
<products>
  <product>
    <id>6789</id>
    <name>shirt</name>
    <color>red</color>
  </product>
  <product>
    <id>6789</id>
    <name>shirt</name>
    <color>blue</color>
  </product>
  <product>
    <id>6789</id>
    <name>pants</name>
    <color>black</color>
  </product>
</products>
```

So I might want to display an output .xml that includes Sam as the name with details on what products he has ordered. (the code is just an example, there would be multiple different products and clients in the full thing)

Update:

What I currently have is for loops that loop through the `product` and return a value when `order` and `id` match however calling `$a/color/text()` will return ALL `color` elements that have the same `<id>` sibling value which is not what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using XQuery 3.0, there is. It introduces the [group by](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-group-by) statement, which groups by a certain element.

In your example example you might want to group by the product id, e.g.:

```
for $product in /products/product
let $id := $product/id
group by $id
return $product
```

In XQuery, [for each](https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Higher-Order_Functions#fn%3afor-each) can always be achieved using a for loop (flowr expression). But there also is a newly introduced `fn:for-each` function which might interest you. For each element in the sequence given as first parameter it will apply a certain function (given as second parameter). So e.g. you could do something like:

```
for-each(/products/product, function($product) { local:doSomethingWithProduct($product) })
```

It might be noteworthy, that what you want to achieve in your example can achieved also using a simple XPath 1.0 expression. You will get all products associated with one id using

```
/products/product[@id = /client/client[@name = "Sam"]/order]
```

There most likely is also a way to emulate group by using purely XQuery 1.0. But this heavily depends on a concrete use case.